# How to create rainbow gradient on a complex shape?

Tags: color, gradient, shapes

How the shape is colored?

How to use gradient in this shape?

[image]

thanks

Comment: That would depend on the software you are using.

Comment: We need to know what software you have available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, there are multiple duplicated and rotated shapes which were colored by SOLID (and NOT gradient) color independently:

[image]

You can see that every basic shape (highlighted on my illustration) has its own color which is solid and not gradient:

[image]

I suppose that basic shape was rotated after mathematical calculations to match 360 degrees. 
The spectrum used is not perfectly "mathematical", probably some calculation was used, but it is pretty simple to create this range "by hand" just moving sliders in color panel.

[image]